# Calculation via factor results in a by-list - how to circumvent?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame as following:

```
  Lot Wafer Voltage Slope Voltage_irradiated Slope_irradiated m_dist_lot
1   8   810   356.119 6.08423    356.427           6.13945          NA
2   8   818   355.249 6.01046    354.124           6.20855          NA
3   9   917   346.921 6.21474    346.847           6.33904          NA
4 (...)
120 9   914   353.335 6.15060    352.540           6.19277          NA 
121 7   721   358.647 6.10592    357.797           6.17244          NA
122 (...)
```

My goal is simple but also a bit difficult. Definitely it is doable to solve it in several ways:
I want to apply a function "func" to each row according to a factor, e.g. the factor "Lot". This is done via

```
m_dist_lot<- by(data.frame, data.frame$Lot,func)
```

This actually works but the result is a by-list:

```
data.frame$Lot: 7

      354       355       363       367       378       419       426       427       428       431       460       477       836 
3.5231249 9.4229589 1.4996504 7.2984485 7.6883170 1.2354754 1.8547674 3.1129814 4.4303001 1.9634573 3.7281868 3.6182559 6.4718306 

data.frame$Lot: 8
         1          2         11         15         17         18         19         20         21         22         24         25 
 2.1415352  4.6459868  1.3485551 38.8218984  3.9988686  2.2473563  6.7186047  2.6433790  0.5869746  0.5832567  4.5321623  1.8567318
```

The first row seems to be the row of the initial data.frame where the data is taken from. The second row are the calculated values.
My problem now is: How can I store these values properly into the origin data.frame according to the correct rows?

For example in case of one certain calculation/row of the data frame:

```
m_dist_lot<- by(data.frame, data.frame$Lot,func)
```

results for the second row of the data.frame in

```
data.frame$Lot: 8
2
4.6459868
```

I want to store the value *4.6459868* in *data.frame$m_dist_lot* according to the correct row "*2*":

```
  Lot Wafer Voltage Slope Voltage_irradiated Slope_irradiated m_dist_lot
1   8   810   356.119 6.08423    356.427           6.13945          NA
2   8   818   355.249 6.01046    354.124           6.20855     4.6459868
3   9   917   346.921 6.21474    346.847           6.33904          NA
4 (...)
120 9   914   353.335 6.15060    352.540           6.19277          NA 
121 7   721   358.647 6.10592    357.797           6.17244          NA
122 (...)
```

but I don't know how. My best try actually is to use "unlist".

`un<- unlist(m_dist_lot)` results in

```
un[1]
6.354 
3.523125 
un[2]
6.355 
9.422959 
un[3]
(..)
```

But I still don't know how I can "separate" the information of "factor.row" and "calculcated" value in such a way that the information is stored correctly in the data frame.

At least when using `un<- unlist(m_dist_lot, use.names = FALSE)` the factors are not present:

```
un[1]
3.523125
un[2]
9.422959
un[3]
1.49965
(..)
```

But now I lack the information of how to assign these values properly into the data.frame.

Using `un<- do.call(rbind, lapply(m_dist_lot, data.frame, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))` results in

```
(...)
7.922    0.94130936
7.976    4.89560441
8.1      2.14153516
8.2      4.64598677
8.11     1.34855514
(...)
```

Here I still lack a proper assignment of calculated values <> data.frame.
I'm sure there must be a doable way. Do you know a good method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reproducible data or an example of what you want `func` to do, I am guessing a bit here. However, I think that `dplyr` is going to be the answer for you.

First, I am going to use the pipe (`%>%`) from `dplyr` (exported from `magrittr`) to pass the builtin `iris` data through a series of functions. *If* what you are trying to calculate requires the full data.frame (and not just a column or two), you could modify this approach to do what you want (just write your function to take a data.frame, add the column(s) of interest, then return the full data.frame).

Here, I first `split` the `iris` data by Species (this creates a list, with a separate data.frame for each species). Next, I use `lapply` to run the function `head` on each element of the list. This returns a list of data.frames that now each only have three rows. (You could replace `head` with your function of interest here, as long as it returns a full data.frame.) Finally, I stitch each element of the list back together with `bind_rows`.

```
topIris <-
  iris %>%
  split(.$Species) %>%
  lapply(head, n = 3) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

This returns:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
5          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
6          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
7          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica
8          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
9          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica
```

Which I am going to use to illustrate the approach that I think will actually address your underlying problem.

The `group_by` function from `dplyr` allows a similar approach, but without having to `split` the data.frame. When a data.frame is grouped, any functions applied to it are applied separately by group. Here is an example in action, which ranks the sepal lengths within each species. This is obviously not terribly useful directly, but you could write a custom function which took any number of columns as arguments (which are then passed in as vectors) and returned a vector of the same length (to create a new column or update an existing one). The `select` function at the end is only there to make it easier to see what I did

```
topIris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(rank_Sepal_Length = rank(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  select(Species, rank_Sepal_Length, Sepal.Length)
```

Returns:

```
     Species rank_Sepal_Length Sepal.Length
      <fctr>             <dbl>        <dbl>
1     setosa                 3          5.1
2     setosa                 2          4.9
3     setosa                 1          4.7
4 versicolor                 3          7.0
5 versicolor                 1          6.4
6 versicolor                 2          6.9
7  virginica                 2          6.3
8  virginica                 1          5.8
9  virginica                 3          7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround with the help of [Force gsub to keep trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593344/force-gsub-to-keep-trailing-zeros) :

```
un<- do.call(rbind, lapply(list, data.frame, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
un<- gsub(".*.","", un)
un<- regmatches(un, gregexpr("(?<=.).*", un, perl=TRUE))

rows<- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = lengths(un)))
colnames(rows)<- c("row_number")
rows["row_number"]<- sprintf("%s", rownames(un))
rows["row_number"]<- as.numeric(un[,1])
rows["row_number"]<- sub("^[^.]*[.]", "", format(rows[,1], width = max(nchar(rows[,1]))))
```