# Force gsub to keep trailing zeros

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I want to extract the digits after "." from data.frame[ ,1] and store them in a second column as following:

```
1 6.354 354 
2 6.355 355
3 6.363 363
4 6.367 367
5 6.378 378
6 6.419 419
7 6.426 426
8 6.427 427
9 6.428 428
10 6.431 431
11 6.460 46
12 6.477 477
(...)
```

To do that I use `gsub(".*\\.", "", data.frame[,1])` but this ignores the zeros as you can see e.g. in row 11.
How can I extract the complete number/all digits after the "."?
The column is numeric.

Comment: What class is your column?

Comment: @LAP It's numeric

Comment: How about `with(df, (V2 - floor(V2)) * 1000)`?

Comment: If it numeric, you may need to first convert it to character with `format` or `sprintf` to have the number of characters i.e. `v1 <- c(6.354, 6.355, 6.460, 6.400, 6.012);
 sub("^[^.]*[.]", "", format(v1, width = 5))
#[1] "354" "355" "460" "400" "012"`

Comment: @akrun Thanks, seems to work!

Comment: @docendodiscimus nice approach was thinking the same, but how about "6.012"?

Comment: @zx8754, good catch. My assumption was that they're going to use those extracted number as numerics later on so that wouldn't matter since only leading zeros will be dropped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is numeric, then we may need to convert it to `character` using `format` or `sprintf`, and then use `sub`

```
sub("^[^.]*[.]", "", format(v1, width = max(nchar(v1))))
#[1] "354" "355" "460" "400" "012"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(6.354, 6.355, 6.460, 6.400, 6.012)
```